# A 10x10x10 cube is comprised of smaller 2x2x2 white cubes - Math Question

Tags: geometry

A 10x10x10 cube is comprised of smaller 2x2x2 white cubes. The outer 6 faces of the large cube are painted red. How many faces of the smaller cubes are in red?

I get that there are 1000/8 = 125 small cubes, but then how I calculate how many red cubes are red? Anyone could explain it step by step? thank you!

Comment: Each of the outer 6 faces of the large cube can be broken into $5\times 5$ smaller faces.

Comment: okay and then???

Comment: And then you have your answer.  Each side has 25 faces and there are 6 sides.

Answer (score 1):

$\frac{10\cdot10\cdot10}{2\cdot2\cdot2}=125$ small cubes, that's true. However, that's not what they are asking. They are asking how many faces of smaller cubes are red. Therefore, just count how many faces are red. There are 6 faces of the large cube, and each face is made up of $5\cdot 5$ faces of smaller cubes. Therefore, there are $6\cdot5\cdot5=150$ red faces of smaller cubes.